# How to Making a Background Task Reschedule Itself

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am trying to make a background task reschedule itself at the end of it's task. but when I go to test it doesn't seem to activate. The task runs initially from the frontend successfully. When I check the lifecycle Events after it finishes I see it's name and two blank ones. When I run the blank ones it runs it, not sure what I am doing that causes them. I am tryin to test with a 16 min time trigger but it doesn't seem to ever run **again**. This is the code:

```
var SleepyBand_TaskName = "DataHandlerTask";
foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
{
    if (task.Value.Name == SleepyBand_TaskName)
    {
        task.Value.Unregister(true);
    }
}
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
var trigger = new TimeTrigger(16, false);
builder.Name = SleepyBand_TaskName;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "SleepyBand_BackgroundTasks.DataHandlerTask";
builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
builder.Register();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TimeTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224843?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) only work for [lock-screen apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977060.aspx).

> On Windows, a background task will only run using a TimeTrigger if you have requested that your app be placed on the lock screen with a call to RequestAccessAsync and the user accepts the prompt

You would need to use a [MaintenanceTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh700517?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: @Michael-PaulMoore If it works don't forget to come back and accept my answer. You can up-vote as well if you think it was good.

Answer (score 0):

eI would just use `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` to start threads. Like this you can reshedule a task:

```
public void Test() {
    Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}

private void DoSomething() {
    //Do Something here....

    //Do Something again...
    Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}
```

If you need delays use something like this: https://actionscheduler.codeplex.com/